# Axisfault 302 when calling wso2 web services

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, axis, wso2-identity-server

I am using the below code to register a user in wso2 IS 5.1:

```
  public static void main (String args[]){
    try {
        UserInformationRecoveryServiceStub stub = new UserInformationRecoveryServiceStub("https://localhost:9443/UserInformationRecoveryService");
        RegisterUser user=new RegisterUser();
        UserIdentityClaimDTO claim=new UserIdentityClaimDTO();
        claim.setClaimUri("https://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress");
        claim.setClaimValue("althaf.ashraf@gmail.com");
        UserIdentityClaimDTO[] claims=new UserIdentityClaimDTO[2];
        claims[0]=claim;
        user.setUserName("user10");
        user.setPassword("123456");
        user.setProfile("default");
        user.setTenantDomain("carbon.super");
        user.setUserIdentityClaimDTOs(claims);
        util.registerUser(user);
    } catch (AxisFault e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UserInformationRecoveryServiceIdentityMgtServiceExceptionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And I am getting the below AXIS error

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 302 Error: Found
```

When I use it through a SOAP client like SOAPUI I am able to access the web service successfully.

When I looked into this have seen that this might happen if the WSDL internally uses HTTP and then redirect to HTTPS.

Is there a way to figure out what I am missing here?

Comment: Hi Althaf, could you please let us know the way that you have generated the UserInformationRecoveryServiceStub? Also if could please share the generated stub and the util implementation with us.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the following example code I wrote to register a user using **UserInformationRecoveryService**.

```
import org.apache.axis2.AxisFault;
import org.apache.axis2.client.Options;
import org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient;
import org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext;
import org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory;
import org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HttpTransportProperties;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.stub.UserInformationRecoveryServiceIdentityMgtServiceExceptionException;
import org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.stub.UserInformationRecoveryServiceStub;
import org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants;

import java.io.File;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
public class RegisterUserTest {

    /**
     * User Name to access WSO2 Carbon Server
     */
    private static String USER_NAME = "admin";

    /**
     * Password of the User who access the WSO2 Carbon Server
     */
    private static String PASSWORD = "admin";

    /**
     * Server url of the WSO2 Carbon Server
     */
    private static String SEVER_URL = "https://localhost:9443/services/";

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        /**
         * trust store path.  this must contains server's  certificate or Server's CA chain
         */
        String trustStore = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator +
                "src" + File.separator + "main" + File.separator +
                "resources" + File.separator + "wso2carbon.jks";

        /**
         * Call to https://localhost:9443/services/   uses HTTPS protocol.
         * Therefore we to validate the server certificate or CA chain. The server certificate is looked up in the
         * trust store.
         * Following code sets what trust-store to look for and its JKs password.
         */

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustStore);

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "wso2carbon");

        /**
         * Axis2 configuration context
         */
        ConfigurationContext configContext;

        try {
            configContext = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem( null, null);
            String serviceEndPoint = SEVER_URL + "UserInformationRecoveryService";

            UserInformationRecoveryServiceStub stub = new UserInformationRecoveryServiceStub(configContext, serviceEndPoint);
            ServiceClient client = stub._getServiceClient();
            Options option = client.getOptions();

            option.setProperty(HTTPConstants.COOKIE_STRING, null);
            HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator auth = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();
            auth.setUsername(USER_NAME);
            auth.setPassword(PASSWORD);
            auth.setPreemptiveAuthentication(true);
            option.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, auth);
            option.setManageSession(true);

            stub.registerUser("fazlan", "Abcd123#", null, null, "carbon.super");

        } catch (AxisFault e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UserInformationRecoveryServiceIdentityMgtServiceExceptionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You need to copy the Identity server keystore into the resources directory for SSL handshake purpose.

Following is the **pom.xml** I used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>stack.overflow.is</groupId>
    <artifactId>adminservice</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>wso2-nexus</id>
            <name>WSO2 internal Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <!--<updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy> -->
                <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>wso2.releases</id>
            <name>WSO2 internal Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <!--<updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy> -->
                <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.identity</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.stub</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Encounter this kind of message too. 
Try to access webservice but shows:
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 302 Error: Found.

Turns out that the reason is that I access wrong domain name of webservice URL.So I can not get right SSL certificate.So I guess it is something about SSL.